# Google linechart - set smaller amplitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm working on a linechart that shows prices for products. The problem is that the chart has a huge amplitude so it's very disarranged.

[image]

So if the range of Y axis would be bigger (let's say 800 - 1500) the amplitude would look smaller and the chart would be better arranged.

Do you know how to do that?

This is the code, in fact, it joins multiple datasets.

```
<script>
    function range(start, end) {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            array.push(i);
        }
        return array;
    }


    function drawChart() {
        var google_chart_json = {{ google_chart|safe }};
        var datas = [];
        $.each(google_chart_json, function (key, val) {
            var domain = key;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('datetime', domain + 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', domain);


            $.each(val, function (_, scan) {
                var year = scan[0][0];
                var month = scan[0][1];
                var day = scan[0][2];
                var hour = scan[0][3];
                var price = scan[1];

                data.addRows([
                    [new Date(year, month-1, day, hour), price]
                ]);
            });
            datas.push(data);
        });
        var joinedData = datas[0];
        $.each(datas, function (index, datatable) {
            console.log('joining index ' + index)
            if (index != 0) {
                joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(joinedData, datatable, 'full', [[0, 0]], range(1, index + 1), [1]);
            }
        });


        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));

        chart.draw(joinedData, {
            height: 500,
            width: 1000,
            interpolateNulls: true,
            explorer: {
                maxZoomOut: 10,
                keepInBounds: true
            },
        });
    }
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
{#    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});#}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the range for the Y-Axis by using the `vAxis.viewWindow` option...

```
vAxis: {
  viewWindow: {
    min: 800,
    max: 1500
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. And is it possible to make it depends on max and min values? I know that I can go through JSON and find max and min but maybe there is a more simple way...

Comment: Yes, the data table has a method -- getColumnRange -- it takes the column index and returns object with properties for min and max